# Variable with scope for the selected functions

Tags: javascript

Please bear with me if this is simple question. In javascript, how can I create a variable that has scope to the selected functions? For example, I want variable var1 which can be updated with function1() and function2() but not with any other functions. Is it possible?

Comment: you can by define prototype to some specif object and that method also bind to the same object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible to do this by creating a closure with an IIFE:

```
(function() {
    var secretVar = 1;

    window.func1 = function() { };
    window.func2 = function() { };
})();
```

Now only `func1()` and `func2()` will be able to access `secretVar`

Answer (score 1):

You can create the scope this way:

```
function MyScope(x) {
    this.x = x;
    this.function1 = function (val) {
        this.x = val;
    };
}
```

Then instantiating an object would be the following:

```
var myObject = new MyScope(5);
myObject.function1(10); // Changes x to 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to define those functions with a restricted scope

```
var scope = function() {

    var scopedVariable = "Hi";
    var func1 = function() { /* hi */ }
    var func2 = function() { /* hi */ }
}
// scopedVariable is undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(function() {
    var a = 1;
    window.inc = function() {
        a++;
    }
    window.showA = function() {
        alert(a);
    }
})();
inc();
showA();
```

Comment: it's usually a good idea to include some kind of explaination along with any code.

Answer (score -2):

If you're using a library like lodash (http://lodash.com) or underscore (http://underscore.com) you can use the _.bind function to give the function a specific 'this' scope.

This is from their example in http://lodash.com/docs#bind

```
var func = function(greeting) {
  return greeting + ' ' + this.name;
};

func = _.bind(func, { 'name': 'moe' }, 'hi');
func();
// → 'hi moe'
```

Comment: You're not binding a variable. You're binding a constant value `"hi"` as an argument to the `greeting` parameter. Even if `"hi"` was stored in a variable, you're still just binding the current value of the variable, so the functions have no shared access to that variable.